# possible to get color select option in woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, colors, woocommerce

I have an issue where the client is requesting that I put in a "color box" to select options of the product in wordpress... is that possible?

I don't really think there's an easy way I can do it, but if there's anyone with any experience in woocommerce with some advice, I would greatly appreciate it.

here's a screenshot of what I am hoping to achieve.

Thanks

http://malbert.me/clientflies/screenshotproduct.png

Comment: Link is not working ..Give new link.

Comment: http://malbert.me//clientfiles/screenshotproduct.png

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom meta box for display color box section in add or edit product page.

for example in my case
i added commission box for property type post type:
below is code which i use

add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'add_commission_box_properties');

```
   function add_commission_box_properties(){
   add_meta_box('wp_prop_commission', 'Commission for this property',  
   'wp_commission_box_callback',    'estate_property', 'side', 'high');
}
    function wp_commission_box_callback()
   {
   global $post;
    $property_commission ='';

   $prop_com_array = array();

    $prop_com_array =   get_post_meta($post->ID, 'property_commission', true) ;

if(!empty($prop_com_array))
{
$array_rev = array_reverse($prop_com_array);
$property_commission = $array_rev[0]['rate'];
echo '<strong>Property commission value:  </strong>  '.$property_commission .'  %';
echo '<br/>';
if(count($prop_com_array)>1)
{
echo '<p>Review for previous commission charges for this property</p>';
echo '<table><tbody>';
foreach($prop_com_array as $single_com)
{
     echo '<tr><td style="width:50px;"> '.$single_com['rate'].'  %</td>   
     <td>'.$single_com['date'].'</td></tr>';
}
echo '</tbody></table>';
}
}else
{
    echo '<strong style="text-align:center">No commission value added</strong>';
}
```

}

>

```
add_action('save_post', 'wp_property_check_status_update_property', 1, 2);
```

Comment: I see, so basically a custom field with the color selections? Does all of that, and the add_action go into the functions file?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I can't get that to work though... nothing happens when I update it in my functions framework file.

Comment: thanks for the help, I just had the client pay for a woocommerce extension that allows this and also made it dynamic.  Have a good 2015!

Comment: same to you : @Mixmastermiike